# Setting up IDLE with Python 3 in Fedora

Tags: fedora, ide, python3

I am trying to setup IDLE to use Python 3 by default in my Fedora 23 computer. Every time I am pulling it up it keeps on using the Python 2 interpreter. Is there a file that I need to configure so that it will utilize the Python 3 interpreter by default?

Comment: Tried running `idle3`?

Comment: I just did, and it perfectly pulled up IDLE with Python 3 as the interpreter. Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[python3-tools](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/python3-tools) is a collection of tools included with Python 3 that provides the idle3 program which it installs to `/usr/bin/idle3` and it also installs idle3.4 to `/usr/bin/idle3.4`.

To install python3-tools type:

```
sudo yum install python3-tools
```

Comment: There is also 'python3-tkinter' in the default repos, if you want to save some diskspace.